# In Ruby, how can I collect each new element passing through a method into an array?

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a small prime number program, and am confused about one thing.

I have a function called `create_numbers`, that generates numbers and passes them to a new function called `check_for_primes`, which passes only prime numbers to a final function called `count_primes`.  I want to collect each prime into an array in the function `count_primes`, but for some reason each number is collected as its own array.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

**Here is the code:**

```
def create_numbers
  nums = 1
  while nums < 100
    nums = nums + 2
    check_for_primes(nums)
  end  
end

def count_primes(nums)  
  array = []
  array << nums  
  puts array.inspect
end

def check_for_primes(nums)
    (2...nums).each do |i|
      if nums%i == 0
        nums = false
        break
      end
    end
    if nums != false
      count_primes(nums)
    end
end

create_numbers
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to generate a list of prime numbers than this woefully inefficient probably **O(N^3)** algorithm.

Comment: the primes not being collected should be the least of your worries, the algorithm looks pretty bad, try here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Some fast notes: don't override the values of variables, if a variable has a plural name (nums) the it should be a collection (hash/array/...). Don't "return" using puts, return objects. Use enumerators. Use functional programming.

Comment: Once you're done, check out the `prime` library that comes bundled with Ruby. It's all in Ruby and should give you hints what to aim for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
START = 1
STEP = 2

class Integer
  def prime?
    return if self < 2
    (2...self).each do |i|
      return if self % i == 0
    end
    true
  end
end

def create_numbers
  num = START
  while (num + STEP) < 100
    num += STEP
    primes << num if num.prime?
  end
end

def primes
  @primes ||= []
end

create_numbers
p primes
```

When you want to save the 'state' of something, put it in an instance variable (@var).
It'll be accessible outside of the current function's scope.

Also, try naming your variables differently. For instance, instead of 'nums', in the
create_numbers method, use 'num'. Since the variable is only referencing one number at a
time and not a list of numbers, naming it in the plural will confuse people (me included)...

Hope it helps,

-Luke

Comment: Awesome! Exactly the help I needed.  I did in fact re-write the entire algorithm to avoid using functions, but that's another matter. I still wanted to understand the answer to my original question, and you helped with that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

each time into count_primes you put a value into array (which should have a better name, btw). Unfortunately, each time it's a new variable called array and since no one outside the function can see that variable it's lost when the function ends. If you want to save the values you've already found you'll need to set some state outside your function.

I can think of 2 quick solutions. One would be to declare your storage at the top of create_numbers and pass it into both functions.

```
def count_primes(num, arr)

def check_for_primes(nums, arr)
```

The other would be to set a variable outside all the functions, $array, for example to hold the values.

```
$array = []
...
$array << num
```

Since the scope of $array is global (i.e. all functions have access to it) you have access to it from anywhere in the file and can just add things to it in count primes. Note that using globals in this way is generally considered bad style and a more elegant solution would pass parameters and use return values.

Comment: So following your second suggestion, if I set the array outside of all functions, how would I pass the nums from `check_for_primes` into an array outside of the function?

Comment: Using a global, as you say, is kind of overkill. Wrapping this in a class would've solved the problem as you can use `@array` without worry.